# Handle React routes from django, in Django, React Web App

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-role-permissions

I'm developing a Full-Stack Web App using Python Django as Backend and React Js as a backend. And Django Rest Framework for APIs. Now i'm facing issue of restricting users to access only routes having permissions. I want to handle react routes and navbar from django so that users access routes according to permissions given to them. Kindly guide me how can i do it.

I want to handle react routes and navbar from django so that users access routes according to permissions given to them. Kindly guide me how can i do it.

Comment: Please provide minimal code of the attempts you've done to solve this problem